# Use WHERE or FILTER whe creating TempView

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

Is it possible to use `where` or `filter` when creating a SparkSQL `TempView` ?

I have a Cassandra table `words` with

```
word | count
------------
apples | 20
banana | 10
```

I tried

```
%spark

val df = sqlContext
.read
.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
.options( Map ("keyspace"-> "temp", "table"->"words" ))
.where($"count" > 10)
.load()
.createOrReplaceTempView("high_counted")
```

or

```
 %spark

val df = sqlContext
.read
.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
.options( Map ("keyspace"-> "temp", "table"->"words" ))
.where("count > 10")
.load()
.createOrReplaceTempView("high_counted")
```

Comment: use `filter` OR `where` after `load()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do a `WHERE` or `FILTER` without `.load()`ing the table as @undefined_variable suggested.

Try:

```
%spark

val df = sqlContext
.read
.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
.options( Map ("keyspace"-> "temp", "table"->"words" ))
.load()
.where($"count" > 10)
.createOrReplaceTempView("high_counted")
```

Alternatively, you can do a free form query as documented [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-operations).

Spark evaluated statements in [lazy fashion](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-operations) and the above statement is a Transformation. (If you are thinking we need to filter before we load)